# Sharepoint Date Picker cuts off at the bottom of the page

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, css

In Sharepoint 2010, when I create a new task the date picker at the bottom of the page cuts the month in half and not showing all the days. Is there a way to solve this may be with css ?

Comment: Hi Aslan, could you provide us with a screenshot? I think the Z-index of the Date Picker is the cause of this behaviour. Perhaps you can edit this number: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the css code below and it worked like a charm!

```
body #bodyContainer
{
overflow:visible !important;

}
```